# exchange operation can't be performed because you're running another time-consuming operation

Tags: exchange

I'm trying to add/delete a user permission from a public folder but i keep getting this error.

The operation can't be performed because you're running another time-consuming operation. Try again when it completes.

can i stop the operation?

Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you got the error when modifying the permission via EAC, please try to use EMS to add/delete the user permission on Public Folders.

Or please schedule a downtime to reboot all Exchange 2013 servers(CAS & Mailbox) to fix the issue.

PS: This error would occur if there are some bad requests in the background.